# Which Taylor Swift songs are about her exes?

Tags: meaning, taylor-swift

I heard that Taylor Swift sings songs about all her breakups and only skipped Taylor Lautner.

Is this right? And which songs were about which of her ex-boyfriends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Billboard seems to have a [summary](http://www.billboard.com/photos/1484087/taylor-swifts-boyfriend-timeline-10-relationships-their-songs) of each of her (sometimes just rumored) relationships, and the songs that sprang from their fall-outs. I also found additional songs from a [Suggest.com listicle](http://www.suggest.com/music/34071/17-hit-taylor-swift-songs-and-the-ex-boyfriends-theyre-each-about), the [List of Taylor Swift's ex-boyfriends page](http://taylorswift.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Taylor_Swift's_ex-boyfriends) on the Taylor Swift Wikia, and  I'm not sure how accurate any of these sources are, but they each seem to provide at least *some* evidence for their claims, so it's at least a starting point.

#### High School Boyfriends

1. Jordan Alford — Left TSwift for one of her friends

   - "Picture To Burn"
2. Brandon Borello — Left for college and they broke up

   - "Tim McGraw"
   - "Our Song"
   - "Fifteen"
3. Sam Armstrong — Cheated on TSwift

   - "Should've Said No"
4. Drew ??? - Never actually dated Taylor, she just liked him

   - "Teardrops on My Guitar"

#### Post-fame Boyfriends

Note that some of these are rumored romances without official confirmation from TSwift. In order from first to last, we have:

1. Joe Jonas — July 2008 - August 2008

   - "Last Kiss" — negative and right after the breakup
   - "Forever And Always" — also negative and right after the breakup
   - "Better Than Revenge" — about the girl that Joe Jonas left TSwift for
   - "Holy Ground" — more recent and also positive
2. Lucas Till — March 2009 - April 2009

   - No known songs about that relationship
3. Taylor Lautner — August 2009 - December 2009

   - "Back To December" — features TSwift apologizing to a guy she was with, one with "tan skin" and a "sweet smile", so this is rumored to be Lautner
4. John Mayer — December 2009 - February 2010

   - "Dear John" — about the older John Mayer not treating her as well as she would have liked
   - "I Knew You Were Trouble" — May have been about him, may also have been about Harry Styles
5. Cory Monteith — April 2010 - May 2010

   - "Mine" — It apparently has never been confirmed that they were dating, but it seems like that this song was about Monteith
6. Jake Gyllenhaal — October 2010 - January 2011 —

   - "The Last Time" — rumored, though unconfirmed, that this is about Gyllenhaal
   - "All Too Well" — apparently TSwift spent Thanksgiving with the Gyllenhaal family...
   - "We Are Never Getting Back Together" — Also rumored but unconfirmed
   - "State Of Grace" — Also rumored but unconfirmed
   - "Girl At Home" — Also rumored but unconfirmed
   - "The Moment I Knew" — Also rumored but unconfirmed
7. Eddie Redmayne — October 2011 - January 2012

   - This relationship is also unconfirmed, and there don't seem to have been any songs about Redmayne
8. Zac Efron — February 2012 - March 2012

   - Another rumored/unconfirmed relationship with no known songs, Efron and TSwift did do a parody of the rumors in a cover of "Pumped Up Kicks" on Ellen Degeneres's talk show
9. Conor Kennedy — July 2012 - October 2012

   - "Begin Again" — rumored that this is about TSwift's relationship with the younger man
10. Harry Styles — December 2012 - January 2013

    - "Style" - Sounds like his last name... Coincidence?
    - "Out of the Woods" — widely assumed to be about Styles because it references a December romance and a snowmobile accident
11. Adam Young — Never dated

    - "Enchanted" — TSwift met the Owl City frontman, but he was super shy at the time, and later sent a note apologizing; she responded to the note with this song

Comment: wow, eve multiple song foR one breakup ;O

Comment: Well, there was a song `You Belong with Me` with Lucas Till, though.

Comment: @AJ Lucas Till was in the music video for that song, but is there any evidence that the song was actually about him?

Comment: That's what I was going to ask. I did search but found nothing.